# YouTube : content is not available on this app

Tags: youtube

I have a very old tablet that I just use to cast YouTube and Netflix.

It stopped working yesterday, this appears on the screen where the video should be:

```
The following content is not available on this app
Watch on the latest version of YouTube
```

Tapping the second line brings me to the play store with no option to update the app.

Tablet is Android 5 and YT version is 16.4. I'm in Ireland (in case this is being rolled out at different dates globally).

Tried watching in Chrome but there appears to be no way to cast

Any way round this? Thanks.

Comment: The latest Youtube version 18.16 requires Android 8+. `To continue to use YouTube without updating the app, on your mobile browser, go to m.youtube.com.` https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/12318250

Comment: @Robert As I mentioned the web version does not allow me to cast, which is a deal breaker for me. Thanks for the link though, I see there are third party YT players, what would be a good one?

Comment: Looks like [the latest version that supports Android 5.0](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/youtube/variant-%7B%22arches_slug%22%3A%5B%22arm64-v8a%22%2C%22armeabi-v7a%22%2C%22x86%22%2C%22x86_64%22%5D%2C%22dpis_slug%22%3A%5B%22nodpi%22%5D%2C%22minapi_slug%22%3A%22minapi-21%22%7D/) is [16.40.36](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/youtube/youtube-16-40-36-release/youtube-16-40-36-android-apk-download/). Not sure if it may help or not though.

Comment: UPDATE my YT app is working again. I did nothing to fix it, I guess YT saw a drop in revenue and allowed old apps access again.